# How to add smooth scrolling effect on horizontal scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I just saw an answer by Vlad Danila, but can't reproduce the smooth scrolling effect. Can anyone help me?

Here's an example code snippet I put together:

```js
const buttonRight = document.getElementById('slideRight');
const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slideLeft');

buttonRight.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 20;
};
buttonLeft.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft -= 20;
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 145px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#content {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">Click the buttons to slide horizontally!</div>
</div>
<button id="slideLeft" type="button">Slide left</button>
<button id="slideRight" type="button">Slide right</button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the native CSS property [`scroll-behavior: smooth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior), like so:

```js
const buttonRight = document.getElementById('slideRight'); const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('slideLeft');

buttonRight.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft += 20;
};
buttonLeft.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft -= 20;
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 145px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#content {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">Click the buttons to slide horizontally!</div>
</div>
<button id="slideLeft" type="button">Slide left</button>
<button id="slideRight" type="button">Slide right</button>
```

The only downside is that in Safari it only works with a flag [(Ref)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior#Browser_compatibility). To overcome that you can [use a ponyfill](https://scroll-into-view-if-needed.netlify.app/).

Comment: Hello, thanks much for this, I am a little bit curious how to add ponyfill for this element if you are able to tell me, as I am totally newbie here. :(

Comment: It's [very well documented](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-into-view-if-needed#usage). You can install it with NPM or download it locally, then you run the `scrollIntoView()` function.